# How to solve IMAP Gmail Connection error 'Too many login failures'

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap

I am using IMAP to get inbox data of my Gmail in PHP. It shows the error:

`Too many login failures`

I Enabled Allow less secure App access also, but I'm still getting the same error. Please Some one help me.

Comment: sounds like you entered the wrong password too many times, maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following these steps:

Use an App Password: If you use 2-Step Verification, try signing in with an App Password.

Allow less secure apps: If you don't use 2-Step Verification, you might need to allow less secure apps to access your account.

If you recently changed your Gmail password, you might need to re-enter your Gmail account information or completely repeat your Gmail account setup on your other email client.

please unlock captcha(since you have too many failed attempts) n by visiting [this](https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) link